# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Temp#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I stored the image name in DB. I put all my images in *app/assets/images* folder. I print all the images using rails image_tag. But it shows AssetNotFound Error. I also tried some other ways to print the images in browser. I used following methods.

`<%= image_tag temp.img %>`

`<%= image_tag image_path(temp.img) %>`

`<%= image_path(temp.img) %>`

`<img src="<%= root_url %>app/assets/images/<%= temp.img %>`

I tried these all ways. But the problem is not solved. If I put the name directly, it will print the image.

For example

```
<%= image_tag 'hash_tag.jpg' %>
```

prints the image. But the same image name is present in the `temp.img`. If I used

```
<%= image_tag temp.img %>
```

It will through the **AssetNotFound Error** and it shows *The asset "hash_tag.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline*

Please clear my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As referred here in the [image_tag documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) if you passed

```
image_tag(temp.img)
```

It will reproduce:

```
<img src="/assets/[YOUR TAG IMG]" />
```

So I believe that yours should look like this:

```
image_tag("/images/#{temp.img}")
```

Comment: It also not print the images.

Comment: @Shivaperuman If you are debugging, What is the result from temp.img ?